# android hardware back button closing my app but soft back button doesn't

Tags: java, android, android-activity, back, onkeydown

I have a app which i want the back button to not close my app. So from research, I tried following 2 methods separately:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        // Back?
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // Back
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
        } else {
            // Return
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Both methods seem to work on my Nexus 6 which has soft back button (back button is on the screen itself).
However when I had my friend Beta test the app on his One plus 1 device which has hard back buttons, on his phone it closes the app completely. So when he goes back to app, the app launches from scratch.

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I prevent hard back button from closing the app? Do I need to add some extra code for hard back button handling?
2. Is there someway I can test hard back button with simulator as I don't have a device with hard back button.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code should work for both hard / soft back buttons. But it may be that when your activity is moved to the background, the system runs out of memory (eg due to low RAM on device or too many apps running at once) and force closes your activity.

Comment: Or it could be a battery saver, killing the activity or even the "Developer Options > Don't keep activities / Force quit activities" option might be enabled?

Comment: You should only need onBackPressed.  THe key code should never actually fire.